# how can be text shown in wallpaper setting

Tags: android, text, wallpaper

I am new to android. Developing an app on wallpapers. Wallpapers are setting nicely to background. I want to edit a text in it. For example when we click the button to set wallpaper then it should show text on screen that wallpaper has set. Plz help to resolve this problem.
Here is main java.

```
public class Main extends Activity {
  private ImageView hImageViewPic;
  private Button iButton, gButton; 
  private int currentImage = 0;

   int[] images = { R.drawable.r1, R.drawable.r2, R.drawable.r3, R.drawable.r4, R.drawable.r5, R.drawable.r6, R.drawable.r7, R.drawable.r8, R.drawable.r9, R.drawable.r10 };
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

      hImageViewPic = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.idImageViewPic);
       iButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNext); 
       gButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPrev); 

        //Just set one Click listener for the image 

      iButton.setOnClickListener(iButtonChangeImageListener); 
      gButton.setOnClickListener(gButtonChangeImageListener);
        } 
       View.OnClickListener iButtonChangeImageListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        //Increase Counter to move to next Image
        currentImage++;
         currentImage = currentImage % images.length;
          hImageViewPic.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);
           } 
          }; 
         View.OnClickListener gButtonChangeImageListener = new OnClickListener() { 
         `public void onClick(View v) { 

          //Increase Counter to move to next Image 

      currentImage--;
      currentImage = (currentImage + images.length) % images.length; 
      hImageViewPic.setImageResource(images[currentImage]);
  // Button for wallpaper setting

 Button bSetWallpaper=(Button) findViewById (R.id.bSet);
 imageView imagePreview=(imageView) findViewById(R.id.idImageViewPic);
 imagePreview.setOnClickListener (images [currentImage]);
 bSetWallper.setOnClickListener (new Button.onClickListener (){

  @Override
 public void onClick (View arg0){
  WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance (getApplicationContext ());
  try {
 myWallpaperManager.setResource (images [currentImage]);
  } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace ();
  }
    }
  });
  }
 };
 }
```

So plz help in showing text. `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this?

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wallpaper set!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```